# How to enable CIFS in Alfresco on Windows (dialog pops, credentials not accepted)

Tags: windows, authentication, alfresco

I'm trying to make it possible to access/upload documents to Alfresco using shared drive, i.e. CIFS. The server runs on Windows.

I'm able to ping the server like *ping themachine-a*, so I guess the CIFS is up and running in Alfresco. But I'm unable to sign-in at \alfrescomachine\; the dialog window appears but no credentials are 'good enough':
themachine-a\admin, admin
\admin, admin

I'd like to use Alfresco user accounts, therefore I tried setting the authenticator to type="alfresco" in both ../extension/file-server-custom.xml or ../web-inf/classes/alfresco/file-servers.xml. Also I set logging to *debug* for everything under 'CIFS server debugging' in log4j.properties. All with no luck... I would expect to see something in the output console or in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it happens to be [a 2yr old bug](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-4486?focusedCommentId=22192&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#action_22192). (The link also contains a workaround.)